# Maven: war generation and integration tests with different profile

Tags: maven

I am trying to generate the war file of my application for production environment after all integration-tests have passed.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <!-- Profile configuration -->
    <profiles>
        <!-- The configuration of the development profile -->
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <!--
                    Specifies the build.profile.id property that must be equal than the name of
                    the directory that contains the profile specific configuration file.
                    Because the name of the directory that contains the configuration file of the
                    development profile is dev, we must set the value of the build.profile.id 
                    property to dev.
                -->
                <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
                <!--
                Only unit tests are run when the development profile is active
                -->
                <skip.integration.tests>true</skip.integration.tests>
                <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <!-- The configuration of the production profile -->
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>prod</build.profile.id>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <!-- The configuration of the test profile -->
        <profile>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>integration-test</build.profile.id>
                <!--
                   Only integration tests are run when the integration-test profile is active
                -->
                <skip.integration.tests>false</skip.integration.tests>
                <skip.unit.tests>true</skip.unit.tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>

        <filters>
            <!--
                Ensures that the config.properties file is always loaded from the
                configuration directory of the active Maven profile.
            -->
            <filter>utils/profiles/${build.profile.id}/config.properties</filter>
        </filters>

        <resources>
            <!--
                Placeholders that are found from the files located in the configured resource
                directories are replaced with the property values found from the profile
                specific configuration file.
            -->
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.xlt</exclude> <!-- maven corrupt template files otherwise -->
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xlt</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <!-- 
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                     -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>%regex[css/(?!styles).*.css]</packagingExcludes> <!-- Include, separated by comma, with JS minified: app/**/*.js -->
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Plugin to execute unit tests -->
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.20.1</version>
              <configuration>
                <!-- Skips unit tests if the value of skip.unit.tests property is true -->
                <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
                <!-- Excludes integration tests when unit tests are run -->
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/IT*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Plugin to execute integration tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <!--
                        Invokes both the integration-test and the verify goals of the
                        Failsafe Maven plugin
                    -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!--
                                Skips integration tests if the value of skip.integration.tests
                                property is true
                            -->
                            <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Plugin to add extra directories to search during the execution of tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-integration-test-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Configures the source directory of our integration tests -->
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/integration-test/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Add a new resource directory to our build -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-integration-test-resources</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Configures the resource directory of our integration tests -->
                            <resources>
                                <!--
                                    Placeholders that are found from the files located in the configured resource
                                    directories are replaced with the property values found from the profile
                                    specific configuration file.
                                -->
                                <resource>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    <directory>src/integration-test/resources</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

As you can see I use two different profiles: 'prod' and 'integration-test'

If I execute: `mvn verify -Pintegration-test` then the whole process is executed, integration tests are triggered and the war file is generated. The problem is that, as I use 'integration-test' profile (because I use a different config.properties to execute the integration tests), the final war file contains the properties files with the wrong values, they have the 'integration-test' properties instead of 'production' properties.

If I manually activate the 'production' profile (with Eclipse) and execute: `mvn war:war` then the war file for production is successfully generated, but integration tests are not triggered.

What I'm trying to do is combine these 2 steps in one single step, I mean, execute the whole process to perform the integration tests with 'integration-test' profile and have the war file generated with the 'production' profile.

I feel I am missing something about Maven and hope you can guide me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert `<skip.integration.tests>false</skip.integration.tests>` in your prod profile. If you don't want the integration-tests to be executed every time you build with your prod profile, you can manually set this property on the command line with

```
mvn install -Pprod -Dskip.integration.tests=false
```

Comment: Integration tests use a special config.properties file that is different from the config.properties file for production environment, check my '<filters/> section. This way integration tests are only executed successfully with profile 'integration-tests', I cannot use the 'prod' profile for this purpose with my current configuration. What I'm doing as a temporary solution is running 'verify' with profile 'integration-tests' and if the build is success, then execute 'verify' with profile 'prod' and 'skip.integration.tests=true'. My purpose is doing the final build in one single step